# Autofill Bootstrap select dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autofill, bootstrap-select

I have a form which has the option of an 'autofill' button. I've got the autofill button working correctly using jQuery [formautofill](http://labs.creative-area.net/jquery.formautofill/doc/).

The problem I'm having is that I'm using Bootstrap select and I have a title field which isn't changing - is there something specific to Bootstrap select that I have to do in order to change the field when the button is clicked?

My jQuery currently looks like:

```
var data = {
    "title": "1",
    "forename": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "email": "",
    "tel": ""
}
$(".autofill.btn").bind("click", function() {
    $(".autofillForm").autofill(data, {
        //findbyname: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to figure it out. For those ever in need you have to re-render the select box.

This is my finished jQuery

```
var data = {
    "title": "1",
    "forename": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "email": "",
    "tel": ""
}
$(".autofill.btn").bind("click", function() {
    $(".autofillForm").autofill(data, {
        //findbyname: false
    });
    $('select').selectpicker('render');
});
```